# How to prevent uitableview adjust All frame's position Y after scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I add a tableview and a view in storyboard.

After scrolling table view, all frames(table view and top view) position Y will be added 20.

That is:

**before scrolling**

topView.frame.y = 0

tableView.frame.y = 64

**after scrolling**

topView.frame.y = 20

tableView.frame.y = 84

**Then the view will have a blank!**

**Update:** This situation only after I add label or imageview into the cell content view.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is autolayout enabled?

Comment: Yes, I use storyboard with size class

Comment: I new a test project but with same code and size class, but it ok that the tableview will not adjust view.frame's Y position, Im confused

Comment: Make your table view frame equal to self.view frame and deduct 20 in y position for the frame using CGRectMake

Comment: set frame.y = -20  will make your layout hard to adjust

Comment: It could depend on how you have your view hierarchy constructed, but be sure you review the view controller option: `Adjusts Scroll View Insets` you can find this under the Attributes Inspector. It may be playing a role in what you are seeing.

Comment: Yes, I find a lot answers about Adjusts Scroll View Insets, but it not work in this case. Also I am try to edit tableview.contentInset, not work!

Comment: I found this situation only after I add label or imageview into the cell content view.